# What does the output of this program means?

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to get the maximum virtual memory of the current process in Linux. And I am using getrlimit()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

struct rlimit rlim;
getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS,&rlim);
printf("Soft limit %ld",rlim.rlim_cur);
printf("Hard limit %ld",rlim.rlim_max);
```

I get -1 in both values. Shouldn't I expect the virtual memory max allowed for the current process ?

Comment: The value RLIM_INFINITY denotes no limit on a resource (both in the
       structure returned by getrlimit() and in the structure passed to
       setrlimit()).

Comment: I am using RLIMIT_AS

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: the OP isn't printing the return value of the call.

Comment: But I did not use the return value ? I print the value of the field of the structure. shouldn't I do int error= getrlimit() in that case ?

Comment: By default values are set to 1 if you want to change the value you use function setrlimit and change the value of the structure.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin he is printing the structure members.

Comment: @DilipKumar: these values aren't set to 1 by default.

Comment: If you look closely, you will see what is being provided is the value for `RLIM_INFINITY` (`-1`). Not the return, as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `RLIM_INFINITY` denotes no limit on a resource (both in the structure returned by `getrlimit()` and in the structure passed to `setrlimit()`).

These are the default values for a process. Check the value of this constant.